# How to build bff package on AIX?

Tags: aix

What is the standards need to follow to build dff package for AIX?

Comment: Ask on superuser or serverfault. This is not the right site for this sort of question.

Comment: Hi Smith,I updated the question, could you please guide me?

Comment: Again, this is not the correct site for this. Ask on server fault or super user, this site is for programming not system configuration/administration.

Comment: Do you have a reason not to build rpm instead? It is widely used on AIX too, and it does have some documentation.